# Универсальный класс с параметром в виде универсального класса

Tags: c#, generics

Возможно ли, и если да, то как, создать универсальный (generic) класс, параметром для которого выступает другой универсальный класс?

Псевдо-код поясняющий идею:

```
class Gen<T> where T : class { }   // тут всё ОК
class MoreGen<G> where G : Gen { } // здесь непонятно как сделать
```

Хочется ограничить параметры для `MoreGen` только классами `Gen<T>`, чтобы была возможность использовать следующий код:

```
new MoreGen<Gen<AnyClass>>(); // Должно быть OK
new MoreGen<string>();        // Нужна ошибка компиляции
new MoreGen<Gen<int>>();      // Нужна ошибка компиляции
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39907/discussion-on-question-by-alexolut-------).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На основании упомянутого в комментариях [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541152/c-sharp-generic-where-constraint-with-any-generic-type-definition/1541173#1541173) на английском SO, решение "в лоб" не является возможным. Для достижения желаемого эффекта приходится добавлять интерфейс:

```
interface IGen {}
class Gen<T> : IGen where T : class { }
class MoreGen<G> where G : IGen { }

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new MoreGen<Gen<string>>();   // OK
        new MoreGen<Gen<Test>>();     // OK
//      new MoreGen<string>();        // no implicit reference conversion from `string' to `IGen'
//      new MoreGen<Gen<int>>();      // The type `int' must be a reference type
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Результат выполнения кода](http://ideone.com/XVP7JV)</kbd>